# How to display latest viewed post by logged user?

Tags: plugins

I`m working on a online magazine website, and one of the features is to display the last 3 magazines (posts) the user have read.

How do I go about storing that info and displaying back to each user?

Thanks in advance,

Renato.

Comment: You have to keep the record of each and every post read by the user, for this create an API which tracks the user activity on your website. I hope you are handy with PHP development.

Comment: Look on this https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

Comment: @TejasGajjar Re-read the question.